# sequelize transaction level read uncommitted not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize to save a dataset into a postgresql database.
I have set up the isolation level to read uncommitted like that:

```
 sequelize.transaction({
          isolationLevel: sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.READ_UNCOMMITTED
      },transaction => co(function* () {
          ...
      }))
```

but after I have saved a data with id=X if I do a search for the same id i don't get any result

```
Model.findOne({ where }, transaction);
```

Do somebody has any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah. You use a wrong signature. It should be
`Model.findOne({ where, transaction })`. See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findOne

Comment: I have the same error even with the change you suggested

Comment: Strange. I even know from where you did take your example. I faced absolutely the same problem and it helped me

Comment: the strange is that I verified the transaction level befor running the query and it's correctly set up to read uncommitted

Comment: Yes, but you should pass this very transaction to the query. And you do that using `options.transaction`, not a separate parameter